# Convert Object to Boolean[][]

Tags: java

How I can convert an Object to Array of Boolean Arrays?

```
Boolean[][] mass;     
mass = (Boolean[5][5])Object;
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: What would you expect the result to be if the object is, say, a stream?

Comment: What do you have in that Object instance?

Comment: I want to convert an Object from this : mass = (Boolean[5][5])request.getSession().getAttribute("mass");

Comment: You might like to know that `boolean[][]` is up to 4 to 8 times more memory efficient than `Boolean[][]` and you can avoid getting `null`s  Using BitSet can be up to 8x more efficient again ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this answer to your question:

```
Boolean[][] tst = new Boolean[5][5];  
Object obj = tst;       

Boolean[][] mass;     
mass = (Boolean[][])obj;

System.out.println("tst.length = " + mass.length );
System.out.println("tst[0].length = " + mass[0].length );
```

Just cast to `Boolean[][]`.

Printout of the sample:

```
tst.length = 5
tst[0].length = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Object is a class, not an instance. You can't cast the class Object to Boolean[5][5], simply because a Class is certainly not an object of type Boolean[5][5], you might be able to cast a reference of type Object to Boolean[5][5].

Answer (score 1):

The type for an array of Boolean arrays is `Boolean[][]`, regardless of its size. Also, `Object` is a class, and keyword, so your actual object can't be called that.

Example (assuming you have an actual `Boolean[][]` which you just happen to have received with a static type of `Object` ):

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[]_){

        Boolean[][] x = new Boolean[][]{{true,false},{false,true}};

        Object o = x; //say you're given the o object

        Boolean[][] y = (Boolean[][])o; //cast it like this

        for (Boolean[] b : y)
            System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(b));

    }
}
```

If this doesn't work, the [`ClassCastException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) that gets thrown should tell you what the actual class of your object was, and then you'll possibly know how to convert it by hand (stupid example: a string "0101..." with 25 `0`s and `1`s).